# Maximizing the determinant of submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, determinant

Suppose an $n \times n$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $A$, and the objective is to find a $k \times k$ ($1 \leq k \leq n$) submatrix which has the largest determinant amongst others of the same size.

Now, let's say we use a greedy approach, at each step, find a $(k^{\prime}-1) \times (k^{\prime}-1)$ submatrix that has the largest determinant, where $k^{\prime}$ is the size of the matrix in the previous step. Iterate until the desired size $k$ has been reached.

I am trying to come up with examples where this greedy algorithm does not give the true optimum. A toy example, let the matrix $A$ be

\begin{bmatrix} 1&a&b\\a&1+\delta&b\\b&b&1+2\delta \end{bmatrix}

It can be seen that when $a=0.3, b=0.8,\delta=0.1$, and $k=1$, the algorithm won't be able to identify the answer, which is $1+2\delta$. Actually the correct answer got elliminated at the first step.

I am wondering whether there are matrices with some general structure such that this algorithm does not work?